# ¿como pasar datos de un controlador a una vista que no es suya?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc

Por ejemplo tengo el controlador EliminaUsuarios  cuya vista es EliminarUsuarios.cshtml y otra donde el controlador es Usuarios y la vista es Usuarios.cshtml lo que quiero es pasar el valor de  ViewBag.Error en EliminarUsuarios (controlador) a Usuarios (Vista) para ahí poder mostrar el error

```
namespace Sistema.Controllers
{
    public class Usuarios : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Usuarios()
        {
            return(db.Usuarios.Tolist())
        }

        public ActionResult EliminarUsuario
        {
            // ?????????????????aquí regresar a la vista                 
            // Usuarios con el valor de  ViewBag.Error
        }
    }
}


/////////////Vista Usuarios
@model IEnumerable<Sistema.Models.Usuario>
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Usuarios";
}
///Recibir valor de ViewBabag
@ViewBag.Error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu clase debería ser llamada `UsuariosController` en vez de `Usuarios`

```
namespace Sistema.Controllers
{
    public class Usuarios : Controller
    {
      public ActionResult Usuarios()
        {
         ViewBag.Error = TempData["Error"];
         return(db.Usuarios.Tolist());
        }
      public ActionResult EliminarUsuario()
        {           
        TempData.Add("Error", "El detalle del error");
        return RedirectToAction("Usuarios"); 
        }
    }
}

/////////////Vista Usuarios
@model IEnumerable<Sistema.Models.Usuario>
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Usuarios";
}
///Recibir valor de ViewBabag
@ViewBag.Error
```

Como recién andas iniciando con `ASP.net MVC`, te recomiendo visitar el siguiente workshop que realicé el mes anterior: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY

Comment: Gracias ahora si ya quedo  :) @fredyfx

Comment: solo que le cambie un poco y quedo asi  por si alguien mas en el futuro lo llega a necesitar 
TempData["Error"] = "Mensaje";
return RedirectToAction("Usuarios");

Comment: de nada mi estimado, recuerda aceptar la respuesta que mejor se ajuste a lo que buscas :D //a mayor respuestas resueltas, mejor "salud" del sitio en la red de StackExchange :D

Comment: @Antonio: y no olvides también sumar tu voto en aquellas respuestas que te hayan ayudado ;)

Comment: @gbellmann si me acaban de desbloquear esa opción ya se puede ver reflejado en las respuestas gracias :)

Comment: @Antonio aqui tienes http://try.jquery.com/ por cierto, vamos eliminando estos comentarios de tal manera que evitamos generar desorden en la pregunta. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Tienes dos opciones:

1) Retornar un RedirectToAction, lo cual ejecutará el código de la `Action` que llames:

```
public ActionResult EliminarUsuario()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Usuarios");
}
```

2) Retornar directamente una `View` diferente a la que corresponde a la `Action`, pasando su nombre (Devuelve la View sin pasar por la `Action` `Usuarios`):

```
public ActionResult EliminarUsuario()
{
    return View("Usuarios");
}
```